# How django add objects attribute to model classes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

As in the Django documentation

> By default, Django adds a Manager with the name **objects** to every Django model class

How does Django add an attribute to model classes?
Whether it is inherited from the `models.Model` or `Django` add `objects=models.Manager()` dynamically to each model?

Comment: psst! try to find for yourself, it's fun! https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models

Comment: @Kos Yeah ! django add objects dynamically using setattr() function in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's added dynamically to each model class unless you add one yourself.

Have a look at [`ModelBase._prepare`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.4/django/db/models/base.py#L354):

```
def _prepare(cls):
    """Create some methods once self._meta has been populated."""
    opts = cls._meta
    opts._prepare(cls)

    ...

    if not opts.managers:
        if any(f.name == 'objects' for f in opts.fields):
            raise ValueError(
                "Model %s must specify a custom Manager, because it has a "
                "field named 'objects'." % cls.__name__
            )
        manager = Manager()
        manager.auto_created = True
        cls.add_to_class('objects', manager)
```